# How to import spatial (geo) vector data to Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gis, qgis, procedural-generation

I am QGIS user. I want to import spatial data to Unity 3D. It is data similar to the one that Open street map offers - i.e. points, lines and polygons in 2D, with tables with data. It can be import of geojson, geopackage or shapefile. I would like to have spatial geometry with table. Do you know some good tools to do this?

PS. I tried exporting the data from Blender, but line and point data seems to crush then, and does not appear in Unity.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing that a lot and there is quite a steep curve to get things going, if you decide to implement everything yourself (eg. transforming your data to the right coordinate system, parsing the geometry, polygons with holes in them, etc. ).

However, to *simplify* your problem for now, I would export from QGIS to ESRI Shapefile format and then use a reader class to convert your data to geometry.  Start with some points, then lines, and then (multi)polygons

I think such a class can be found found at the [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/synhershko/nettopologysuite/tree/master/NetTopologySuite/IO) or [Shapefile class](https://github.com/abfo/shapefile). I would keep all the data in one projection, for example EPSG:3857 (same as OSM).

Comment: Thanks. I have never installed library in C#, it was fairly easy in Python. Can you give me a hand with it?  And shall I transform shapefiles to another file format? Like Obj? Or Unity would recognize it once libraries are installed.